# Embedded Jetty REST service with Welcome File

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to create a web service that has a REST API and can serve documents such as static html. At the moment I've got the REST (Jersey 2.17) api working fine but I'm struggling to serve up resources such as my index.html

**Project Structure**

```
src
--main
----java
------resource
--------RestResource.java
------app
--------LocalRunner.java
----webapp
------index.html
```

**LocalRunner.java**

```
public class LocalRunner {
    private final Server server;

    public LocalRunner() {
        server = new Server(8315);
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {    
        // REST
        WebAppContext restHandler = new WebAppContext();

        restHandler.setResourceBase("./");
        restHandler.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        ServletHolder restServlet = restHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class,  "/rest/*");
        restServlet.setInitOrder(0);
        restServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "resource");

        // Web
        ResourceHandler webHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        webHandler.setResourceBase("./");
        webHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});

        // Server
        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlers.addHandler(restHandler);
        handlers.addHandler(webHandler);

        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new LocalRunner().start();
    }
}
```

Hitting `localhost:8315/rest/someRestEndpoint` works fine but if I try hit just `localhost:8315` I get a directory structure when I'm expecting my `index.html` welcome file. What am I doing wrong?

*Note I am not using a WEB.XML as I'm trying to do all the configuration in the class above*.

---

**Dependencies if it helps (Gradle)**

```
def jettyVersion = '7.2.2.v20101205';
compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:${jettyVersion}"
compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:${jettyVersion}"
compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:${jettyVersion}"

def jerseyVersion = '2.17'
compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:${jerseyVersion}"
compile "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:${jerseyVersion}"
```

Comment: [Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) - consider upgrading soon (its not safe to run EOL servers on the open internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the request is dispatched to the Handlers in the order they are added to the collection and the `restHandler` must have been setting the response to complete. As a result the request never made it to the `webHandler` and the welcome file was never added to the response. Also the `ResourceHandler` was looking in the base directory for the index.html, setting the `resourceBase` to `src/main/webapp` fixed this.